# Como puedo agregar un array de números dentro de otro array en java

Tags: java, mysql

tengo una consulta, tengo una base de datos de MySQL y los datos los registre en diferentes variables, deseo mostrar esas variables en una tabla, pero los datos los muestra de manera horizontal, es decir no me muestra el dato 1 con la información del dato dos.
Lo que deseo realizar es insertar los datos de las variables en un array, es decir
[[DATO1(i), DATO2(i)], [DATO1(i), DATO2(i)]].

```
 (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    arreglo2[i] = [Conexion.producto.get(i), Conexion.consumo_1.get(i)];
};
```

Esto tratando de hacerlo de esta manera, pero no he conseguido como.
¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

```
static ArrayList<Integer> producto = new ArrayList<>();
//las variables las estoy guardando de esta manera: 
producto.add (rs.getInt("PRODUCTO"))
```

y en los resultados se muestran asi:

```
el producto es: [470430, 1238122, 1017084, 1079809, 1017222, 1195053, 274114, 1253561]

El consumo es: [67, 2, 28, 3, 4, 51, 87, 35]
```

pero deseo que se muestren:

```
El array de producto es: [[470430,67], [1238122, 2]]
```

Ya que los datos que estoy extrayendo deseo mostrarlos en una tabla dinámica para posterior análisis.

El codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    static int columns;
    static Integer array[][] = {};


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
        conexion.conectar();
        columns = Conexion.consumo_1.size();
        String[] cabecera = {"Producto", "Consumo 1", "Consumo 2", "Consumo 3", "Consumo 4"};
        ArrayList<Integer[]> listas = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer arreglo2[] = new Integer[columns];

        System.out.println(arreglo2);
        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                array = new Integer[][]{
                        Conexion.producto.toArray(new Integer[0]),
                        Conexion.consumo_1.toArray(new Integer[0]),
                        Conexion.consumo_2.toArray(new Integer[0]),
                        Conexion.consumo_3.toArray(new Integer[0]),
                        Conexion.consumo_4.toArray(new Integer[0])
                };
        }
        DefaultTableModel data = new DefaultTableModel(array,cabecera);
        JTable table = new JTable(data);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 400);

        JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
        ventana.setLayout(null);
        ventana.setSize(1000, 800);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ventana.add(scroll);

        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido, podrías darnos una muestra de como recibes los datos, y como quieres que queden, completar tu código,y explicar un poco mejor tus necesidades... osea, ayudanos a ayudarte, gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la info en la pregunta!!! evita usar imagenes siempre que sea posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es algo como:

```
salida = {
    { 470430, 67 },
    { 1238122, 2 } 
}
```

puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
int arreglo2[][] = new int[ columns ][];
for( int i = 0; i < columns; i++ ) {
    int aux[] = { Conexion.producto.get( i ), Conexion.consumo_1.get( i ) };
    arreglo2[ i ] = aux;
};
```

o si lo prefieres, puedes reemplazar el código dentro del for por:

```
arreglo2[ i ][ 0 ] = Conexion.producto.get( i );
arreglo2[ i ][ 1 ] = Conexion.consumo_1.get( i );
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.el array quedo como lo quería.

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!.

Comment: quería hacerte otra consulta, me disculpas molestar tanto, tengo otra consulta, cuando intento crear la tabla con el método mostrado en el código, obtengo el error cannot resolve constructor 'defaulttablemodel(int[][],String[])'. como puedo solucionar eso ?

Comment: Te falta agregar un constructor que reciba como parámetros, una matriz de int y un array de String, no se que clase es la que te arroja el error, por lo que no te puedo decir mucho más.

Comment: El problema lo presento en la parte: DefaultTableModel data = new DefaultTableModel(arreglo2, cabecera);, esto esta descrito en el código anterior. No sé cómo debería crear el constructor, espero puedas echarme una mano.

Comment: **DefaultTableModel** es una clase del lenguaje, no tienes que crear ningún constructor, así como está escrito tu código debe funcionar (al menos esa parte), si te arroja un error, dime cual es.

Comment: Ya lo logré solucionar, era por el tipo de lista que estaba usando. El cambio que realice fue int arreglo2[][] = new int[ columns ][]; por: Object [][] arreglo2  = new Object[columns][];. Te agradezco mucho tu colaboracion.

Comment: Grande genio!!!.